# in python inheritance part, why there is an error or a warning shows "does not match signature of base method in class"

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I am learning python at inheriting part. During the class, the instructor showed a code about how to use it.  I am using Pycharm edu. I don't know if this might be the reason.
But I just got this error at the line of "def research(self, field, base)", says:"

```
Signature of method 'TheoreticalPhysicist.research()' does not match signature of base method in class 'Physicist'
```

The code is below, I only got Physicist part. The rest should be fine. If there is any tips I really appreciate that.

```
class Physicist:
    def __init__(self, name, iq=120, looks="handsome", subject="physics"):
        self.name = name
        self.iq = iq
        self.looks = looks
        self.subject = subject

    def research(self, field):
        print("{0} research {1}".format(self.name, field))

    def speak(self):
        print("My name is ", self.name)
        print("I am", self.looks)
        print("Intelligence is ", self.iq)
        print("I like ", self.subject)


class ExpermentalPhysicist(Physicist):
    def __init__(self, main_study, name, iq=120, looks="handsome", subject="physics"):
        self.main_study = main_study
        super().__init__(name, iq, looks, subject)

    def experiment(self):
        print("{0} is in Physics Lab.".format(self.name))


class TheoreticalPhysicist(Physicist):
    def __init__(self, theory, name, iq=120, looks="handsome", subject="physics"):
        self.theory = theory
        super().__init__(name, iq, looks, subject)

    def research(self, field, base):
        super().research(field)
        print("My theory is {0}, it is based on {1}".format(self.theory, base))
```

Comment: That's not an _error_ – it's just PyCharm pointing out a possible bug.

Comment: Hi AKX, thanks, yea, I understand, the thing is I didn't even know why it happens. But still thanks so much for answering.

Answer (score 0):

The message means that the signature of an overloaded method (i.e., a
method of a parent class that is redefined in a child class) must be
the same as in the parent class.  So in class `TheoreticalPhysicist`,
method research *must* be defined as:

```py
def research(self, field):
   ...
```

One solution for your example, is to define `base` as a class
attribute of `TheoreticalPhysicist` as you have done for `theory`.

Another solution is to use keyword arguments for method `research`.
By this way you can basically give the method any argument you want
when you call it.  For instance:

```py
class Physicist:
    def __init__(self, name, iq=120, looks='handsome', subject='physics'):
        self.name = name
        self.iq = iq
        self.looks = looks
        self.subject = subject

    def research(self, field, **kwargs):
        print('{0} research {1}'.format(self.name, field))


class TheoreticalPhysicist(Physicist):
    def __init__(self, theory, name, iq=120, looks='handsome', subject='physics'):
        self.theory = theory
        super().__init__(name, iq, looks, subject)

    def research(self, field, **kwargs):
        super().research(field)
        base = kwargs['base']
        print('My theory is {0}, it is based on {1}'.format(self.theory, base))

p = Physicist('some physicist')
p.research('some field')

p = TheoreticalPhysicist('relativity', 'Einstein')
p.research('my field', base='some stuff')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. This really helps me a lot to review the code and learn python.

Comment: @Edward Could you please consider accepting my answer if it helped you solve your problem?